# Difference between running PHP's built-in server and Symfony's PHP Server

Tags: php, webserver, command-line-interface, symfony

When running PHP with Windows CMD, is there any difference between :

```
c:\projects\php-project-root> php app/console server:run
```

And :

```
c:\projects\php-project-root> php -S localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

The builtin server is a wrapper around PHP server with some extra options for convenience. For example you can specify a docroot or router option.